# windows 7 windows explorer keep on loop restarting windows explorerw

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, infinite-loop

Windows-7 Windows-Explorer  infinite-loop restarting windows explorer(WE). 
It displays WE has stopped working then go to WE is restarting in an loop non stop.
Tried to run WE from Task Manager, no luck.
Tried Upgrading Windows with Windows-7 Original disk, no luck.

Comment: Try booting in Safe mode from boot media. If this is possible, try to rollback to a system restore point from before the problem.

Comment: Thx harrymc - even in save mode it pops up and start looping.... cannot start any program or screen 'reboot' with loop... so frustrated...

Comment: Can you boot to the desktop and can you see and use it?

Comment: Nope immediately when desktop opens the loop start - used Task Mgr file to do anything as it is working  to run dos prompts.

Answer (score 0):

As the desktop is still usable through the Task Manager, you might be able to
do an in-place upgrade install. This will preserve your user accounts, data,
programs, and system drivers (if it works).

For detailed instructions, see the article
[How to Do a Repair Install to Fix Windows 7](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html).

You will need to create a boot media of Windows 7 that is of the same
Service Pack as your Windows (probably SP2).
If the computer is not usable for that,
you might need to prepare it on another computer.

Comment: Thx will do and keep you updated.

Comment: @sarelSwart I thought you already tried this? You mentioned that you did, in your question, “Tried Upgrading Windows with Windows-7 Original disk”

Comment: Hi Ramhound, Yes - looping were present the whole time, on 'Gathering files, settings and programs' it stayed on 11% for the whole morning 8-10 hours - so I presumed it freezes and quick rebooted....

Comment: Let it have more time, as the Explorer loop may slow it down. You are starting `setup.exe` from the boot media?

Comment: I rebooted and initiated Setup again with Windows 7 (SP1) DvD again, tried to run Reimage Repair - would not allow me as it said I am not the Administrator it is now in a loop of 'Setup is starting' and 'WE has stopped' and 'WE is restarting' ... I will leave it to run overnight.

Comment: Hi All -- I installed Windows 7 again from setup original disk (SP 1) and Windows Explorer is still looping :-(

Comment: Did you wipe out the existing installation, or did you only do an inplace upgrade (meaning doing the upgrade from inside Windows and specifying to keep data & apps)?